# RabbitMQ WCF service hosting in IIS/WAS

Tags: .net, wcf, rabbitmq, amqp, was

I would like to use RabbitMQ (as a replacement for MSMQ) with WCF and I'd like to host these WCF services in IIS/WAS.  Unfortunately it seems from the documentation that accompanies the RabbitMQ .NET client library that this configuration is "untested and unsupported".

I'm no WCF expert, but my understanding is that the reason for this being unsupported is because the RabbitMQ WCF implementation uses a completely new transport binding element.  WAS has no knowledge of this and based on my reading of this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx would require some unmanaged software writing in order for WAS to properly setup the routing of incoming AMQP messages to the appropriate IIS application and service endpoint.

I'd be grateful if anyone could confirm whether my understanding is correct and/or whether there are any alternative approaches to hosting a RabbitMQ WCF service in IIS/WAS without needing to write any unmanaged code e.g. perhaps a customisation of the net.tcp transport binding element?

Comment: Hey there, 2017 here - did you ever get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 1):

See this question: [AMQP AmqpBinding IIS/WAS problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191448/amqp-amqpbinding-iis-was-problems)

A response there points to the UDP Activator sample. I have a similar problem. I would like to use IIS/WAS for all the benefits that AppFabric brings, and I want to allow push messaging over the MQ.

If I find any other options apart from writing a new AMQP activator listener I will try to document them here. Can't believe that WAS isn't ready for this.

Comment: Hey there, 2017 here - did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Good lord, is this Pete McEvoy of Ammado fame? If so, Frank here, you'll remember me. Don't know if it answers your question but we didn't use Rabbit MQ and didn't try to write a WAS activator. I think we ended up working around the problem, but we did proof of concept (successfully, if I recall) using the on-prem version of Azure Service Bus (Azure Pack they used to call it) with AMQP. It was a long time ago though.  The specific problem above is having an App Fabric process activated on incoming message.This is supported for certain WAS activators.I think our workaround was AMQP out+MQ in.